# How to prove triangle inequality for the metric $d(x,y)=\frac{2|x-y|}{\sqrt{\left(1+|x|^2\right)}+\sqrt{\left(1+|y|^2\right)}}$

Tags: metric-spaces

How to prove triangle inequality for the metric $$d(x,y)=\frac{2|x-y|}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}+\sqrt{1+|y|^2}},$$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{C}?$

Comment: What is the motivation for this? Hyperbolic geometry on the Poincaré disc model?

Comment: This seems to be difficult. All answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1104145/42969 are only partial solutions (or wrong).

Comment: Are you sure that it *is* a metric? For example, should the radicals in the denominator he multiplied rather than added? No typo here?

Comment: ... in that case it would be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1090222/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1159327/42969.