# Is $\lbrace \infty \rbrace$ bounded in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, riemann-sphere

Is $\lbrace \infty \rbrace$ bounded in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$? While $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ can be identified as the riemann sphere I think you could choose $U_1(\infty) = \lbrace z \in \hat{\mathbb{C}} | \parallel z - \infty \parallel < 1\rbrace\subset \hat{\mathbb{C}}$. But $\infty - 1 = \infty$? So its kind of bounded and unbounded. I dont know. How can a set with only one point be unbounded?

Comment: What does $\|\cdot\|$ mean in this context?

Comment: The metric on $\mathbb{C}$ does not directly induce a metric on its compactification, so it is not very clear to me what definition of "bounded" you want to use.

Comment: $\| \cdot \|$ must be the cordal metric

Comment: I mean... once you equip any metric space with a metric, you have $\{x\}\subseteq B(x,r)$ for any $r>0,$ so any singleton will, in particular, be bounded. You need to equip the Riemann sphere with a metric, though.

Comment: Lets use the chordal metric (had a typo in the comment before)

Comment: The notion "bounded" is not useful for $\widehat{\mathbb C}$, since with the standard metric, the whole space is bounded.  You may, however, see the fact that $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ is compact used on occasion.  You are right that something like $\|z - \infty\|$ is not useful for describing $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ near the point $\infty$.

Comment: For any metric $d$ on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ that realizes the usual topology on it, any set in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is necessarily bounded with respect to $d$ simply because $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ itself is bounded. (This follows from the fact that $d$ is continuous on the compact set $\hat{\mathbb{C}}\times\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, hence achieves a finite maximum.)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a "bounded set" usually occurs in metric spaces $(X,d)$. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set. So we have to define a metric on $\hat{\mathbb C}$. This metric generates a topology on $\hat{\mathbb C}$. In order to obtain something *reasonable* we must require that the subspace $\mathbb C$ of $\hat{\mathbb C}$ receives its standard topology. As you know, this is satisfied by the chordal metric $d_c$. Writing $d_c(x,y) = \lVert x -y  \rVert$ is courageous because $\hat{\mathbb C}$ is not a normed linear space. However, if has a reasonable interpretation. If $S^2$ denotes the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$, we may identify $\hat{\mathbb C}$ with $S^2$. This is done via stereographic projection (this is a homeomorphism $h : S^2 \setminus \{(0,0,1)\} \to \mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C$ which extends via $(0,0,1) \mapsto \infty$ to a homeomorphism $H : S^2 \to \hat{\mathbb C}$). With this identification we may use the norm on $\mathbb R^3$ to get a metric on $S^2 \subset \mathbb R^3$. We simply define $d_c(x,y) = \lVert H^{-1}(x) - H^{-1}(y) \rVert$. You will see that this construction produces the chordal metric on $\hat{\mathbb C}$. See [Chordal Metric - Showing it is in fact a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1159327).

But $S^2$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^3$, thus any subset of $S^2$ is bounded with respect to the norm-induced metric on $S^2$. This transfers to subsets of $\hat{\mathbb C}$ with respect to the chordal metric.