# To prove the triangle inequality for the given metric

Tags: metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

I need to prove that the metric defined by

$d(x,y)=\frac{2|x-y|}{\sqrt{1+|x^2|}\sqrt{1+|y^2|}}$

forms a metric on the set of all complex numbers.
I am facing problem with the denominator in proving the triangle inequality as the term in the denominator is under square root and there is also modulus inside it. Need help in proving this.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that the triangle inequality holds for a metric on $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104145/proving-that-the-triangle-inequality-holds-for-a-metric-on-mathbbc)

Comment: @guidoar It's not the same function, but I am curious if OP made a typo now, or if the chordal metric was in fact intended...

Comment: @BrianMoehring: There is, however, a second answer to that question that (mistakenly!) **does** deal with the function in this question.

Comment: @BrianMoehring you're right, but from Brian M. Scott's comment and a quick search (a comment on the referenced answer talks about a well known 'chordal metric') I found  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159327/chordal-metric-showing-it-is-in-fact-a-metric) which seems to deal with OP's question.

Comment: I could not understand most of the things from the two answers mentioned in the above comments. If there is any other way out, kindly help me with that.

Comment: Hint: try stereographic projection.